Run Playwright script through K6
I would like to give load of multiple users from K6 tool and the automation script is recorded in Playwright. When I run the script using K6 run test.js getting below error.
Value is not an object: undefined
import { exec } from 'k6/execution';
import { sleep } from 'k6';
export let options = {
stages: [
    { duration: '10m', target: 10 }, // Ramp up to 10 users over 1 minute
    { duration: '9m', target: 10 }, // Stay at 10 users for 9 minutes
    { duration: '1m', target: 0 }   // Ramp down to 0 users over 1 minute
    ],
thresholds: {
    http_req_duration: ['p(95)<500'], // Thresholds for response time
    }
};

export default function () {
    exec('playwright test HRH.spec.js'); // Execute the Playwright script via command line
    sleep(1); // Add some delay if needed
}

getting error in exec function.
Below are code from HRH.spec.js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
});

Standalone Plywright script run result
C:/k6project/tests> npx playwright test .\HRH.spec.js --headed

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 HRH.spec.js:3:5 › test (1.3s)

  1 passed (3.0s)

Above script with K6 tool run result
C:/k6project/tests>k6 run script.js

          /\      |‾‾| /‾‾/   /‾‾/
     /\  /  \     |  |/  /   /  /
    /  \/    \    |     (   /   ‾‾\
   /          \   |  |\  \ |  (‾)  |
  / __________ \  |__| \__\ \_____/ .io

     execution: local
        script: script.js
        output: -

     scenarios: (100.00%) 1 scenario, 10 max VUs, 40s max duration (incl. graceful stop):
              * default: Up to 10 looping VUs for 10s over 3 stages (gracefulRampDown: 30s, gracefulStop: 30s)

ERRO[0000] TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined
        at file:///C:/k6project/tests/script.js:51:9(5)  executor=ramping-vus scenario=default source=stacktrace
ERRO[0000] TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined
        at file:///C:/k6project/tests/script.js:51:9(5)  executor=ramping-vus scenario=default source=stacktrace


Thanks for the reply. Added in Question only.  HRH.spec.js file is a playwright js file.

oh ok. I have updated the script. I run the playwright script HRH.spec.js with below command npx  playwright test .\HRH.spec.js

Have added screenshots of errors as well.

Ohk. Added screenshots contents as text.

It looks like there is an extension for that: https://github.com/nicholasvuono/xk6-playwright (can't say if it works, I haven't used it yet, just came across it myself)


You are confusing k6/execution with the xk6-exec extension.
k6/execution comes built-in with k6 since version 0.35 (November 2021).

k6/execution provides the capability to get information about the current test execution state inside the test script. You can read in your script the execution state during the test execution and change your script logic based on the current state.

It is imported and used as follows:

import exec from 'k6/execution';
export default function () {
  console.log(exec.scenario.name);
}


It's an object and not a function that can be called.

Then there's xk6-exec:

A k6 extension for running external commands.

xk6-exec has a slightly different API:

import exec from 'k6/x/exec';
export default function () {
  console.log(exec.command("date"));
  console.log(exec.command("ls",["-a","-l"]));
}


(that's 'k6/x/exec', as opposed to 'k6/execution').
But still, exec is not a callable function, but an object. The object has the property command which is a callable function. You might be able to change your import to import { command } from 'k6/x/exec' or import { command as exec } from 'k6/x/exec' to have the command function available as a global function, or to alias it to exec, respectively.
To be able to use extension, you must compile k6 yourself with the xk6 system. Once you have your custom k6 binary, you can run your test scripts with it and import k6/x/exec.
One more thing to note: exec.command does not take a string that is evaluated by a shell. Instead, it provides an API inspired by execv, which means you must provide the arguments in a single array, with each argument being an array element. Something like:
exec.command('playwright', [ 'test', 'HRH.spec.js' ]);

